# Regex find strings that include parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of strings, namely file paths. I want to find all the paths that match a query. My problem is files that have `()` in them cause the regex I was using doesn't work with those.

So if I have the following array:

```
100 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150863248706/Dual Ring (1).gif"
101 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150863248706/Dual Ring (2).gif"
102 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150863248706/Dual Ring.gif"
103 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150864989651/Infinity (1).gif"
104 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150864989651/Infinity.gif"
105 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150865699474/Infinity (1).gif"
106 => "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\images/uploads/15150866060006/Infinity (1).gif"
```

So if the query is `Infinity (1).gif`, it should return 103, 105 and 106.

This is what I'm using in PHP:

```
$query = 'Infinity (1).gif';
$files_found =  preg_grep('/\b'.$query.'\b/i', $files); //Files is the array of file paths
```

Here is a link to regex101 that I've been using: https://regex101.com/r/poesBK/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses `()` have special meaning in regex patterns denoting capture groups, so they must be escaped.  You can escape them or use [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), especially if there may be other special characters such as from user input:

```
$files_found = preg_grep('/\b' . preg_quote($query, '/') . '\b/i', $files);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need regex to find a specific string in another string. 
you can do the following :

```
<?php 

 $files = [
  'path/to/file/image (1).png',
  'path/to/file/image.png',
  'path/to/file/image (9).png',
  'path/to/file/JifOrGif.gif'   
 ];

 $search = 'image (1).png';

 foreach($files as $file) 
 {
  if(strpos($file,$search) !== 0)
  {

      echo 'FOUND ['. $file . '] !';

  }
 }
```

Comment: Why not use `array_search`?

Comment: @azjezz I know, but preg_grep really simplifies all that. And since this search will happen several times in a row, it would be better this way.

Comment: you can make it a function, also using strpos is way much better than using regex. try to avoid using regex as much as you can

Comment: You can use `array_filter` with a test function that calls `strpos()`.

Comment: instead of using `array_filter`, i used a `foreach` loop, which does the same